# Squeaky voice with Microsoft Teams on eOS and iodéOS

Tags: audio, voip, microsoft-teams, fairphone-3, fairphone-4

On both Android phones I own (all systems up-to-date), MS Teams calls are not usable, since the caller voices are all squeaky. I have the impression that a compression algorithm in the background is not doing its job properly.

The phones are a Fairphone 4 (with the latest eOS) and a Fairphone 3 (with the latest iodéOS). The problem occurs every time someone calls, both with and without video. Everything else seems to be working fine, just voice is unusable.

Some internet searches reveal that the issue might not be related to MS Teams itself, but I doubt that, since normal calls and VOIP works just fine. So the question is: is there a workaround, some package that I’m missing, or is MS Teams plainly incompatible with de-Google-d operating systems?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. I don't use MS Teams, but I can't think of what Google components have anything to do with voice calls/transmission. Also, if that's the case, then there may be other reports of users using custom ROM (without flashing Google apps) and MS Teams.

Comment: You're right; usually, software relying on Google APIs (mostly Google Play, actually) just plainly doesn't work. It just baffles me entirely why everything else is working just fine. Plus, when I still had FairphoneOS on both smartphones, MS Teams did work, too.